# Detecting full-screen Direct3D applications

Tags: directx, fullscreen, direct3d

Is there any way to detect - through the Direct3D API - Direct3D applications running in full-screen mode?

[SHQueryUserNotificationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762242%28VS.85%29.aspx), which can [indicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762533%28VS.85%29.aspx) such applications, is only supported on Vista and up. It also only works when the Explorer shell is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to detect full-screen Direct3D and OpenGL (for example Minecraft) applications.

Call [IDirectDraw7::TestCooperativeLevel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426158.aspx). This function returns `DDERR_EXCLUSIVEMODEALREADYSET` if active full-screen Direct3D application is running or if user session is not active (Win+L, Alt+Ctrl+Del, Fast User Switching, etc).

Note: Call `DirectDrawCreateEx` with `DDCREATE_EMULATIONONLY`. This dramatically reduces resources usage by IDirectDraw7.

I have tested this method only in Windows 7 SP1 x64 with 1 display.

---

BTW `SHQueryUserNotificationState()` returns `QUNS_BUSY` instead of `QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN` for full-screen games. Strange...

Comment: What about after .net 3.5, should [CheckDeviceState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) be used instead ? i.e. This method replaces IDirect3DDevice9::TestCooperativeLevel, which always returns S_OK in Direct3D 9Ex applications.

Comment: SHQueryUserNotificationState() returns only 3 (QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN) when: a) The window is on the desktop screen/main screen, is a direct3d window, maximized and the taskbar is not visible. When the taskbar is visible it returns 2 (QUNS_BUSY) because, although it is fullscreen/maximized it does not using the whole screen because of the taskbar. It's also returns 2 (QUNS_BUSY) when a normal window/video is maximized on the main screen. A DirectX window start always maximized on the main screen, so if the function returns 3 it's always there. When is on another screen it rerturns 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'IDirect3DDevice9::GetDisplayMode':

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174387%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
HRESULT GetDisplayMode(
  UINT  iSwapChain,
  D3DDISPLAYMODE * pMode
);
```

> Parameters:
>
> iSwapChain[in]

```
An unsigned integer specifying the swap chain.
```

> pMode[out]

```
Pointer to a D3DDISPLAYMODE structure containing data about the
```

> display mode of the adapter. As
>   opposed to the display mode of the
>   device, which may not be active if the
>   device does not own full-screen mode.