# How to know if computer is in gaming mode

Tags: c++, windows

#### Background

I'm implementing a simple WIN32 application consist of a window.
The user may show/hide the window using a special hotkey. I register the hotkey using [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) and respond to [WM_HOTKEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279(v=vs.85).aspx)

#### Problem

if user plays a game and accidentally (or not accidentally) press the hotkey combination, then my window pops up and as a result the game is minimized.

#### Question

Is there a (native) way to know that the user is in gaming mode, or any other special mode, that I could disable the hotkey response

#### Note

I would also like if windows would make this a feature while I play games. For example don't respond to WinKey+D while I'm in gaming mode.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1219454/103167

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `SHQueryUserNotificationState` function to determine whether the user is playing a full screen D3D game. It will report `QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN`.